# Do ANOVA & MANOVA require balanced levels?

Tags: anova, sample-size, unbalanced-classes, manova, down-sample

I have one independent variable with two levels, or categories, and four dependent variables.

When doing a MANOVA or ANOVA test, how important is it for the number of observations in each category to be balanced?

Right now 35% of my observations are in category 1 and 65% are in category 2.

Should I randomly undersample category 2 so I have an equal number of observations in each category?

Comment: Welcome to CV! Is the variance similar for both categories?

Comment: Thanks @FransRodenburg! I’ll check the variances of each dependent variable across both categories later today. If they’re similar, is it ok to leave the data as-is? Also, what would you consider to be the limit for “similar”?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Homogeneity of variance is an assumption in both ANOVA and MANOVA. The chances of violating this assumption is greater if the sample sizes for each level are different. 
This [link](https://scholarscompass.vcu.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=5026&context=etd) is helpful in understanding if you can instead use Welch's F test.